# udev rule not working

Tags: linux, bash, mount, udev

I am trying to write a udev rule for USB drive plugin. I want to first mount it to `/media` and then run the script at `/usr/local/bin/script.sh`. When I insert the USB, it doesn't even mount the device with this rule. However, If I manually type the part in RUN into terminal, It mounts and executes script.

The rule file says:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", RUN+="/bin/mount -t auto /dev/%k /media/ && /usr/local/bin/script.sh"
```

Is this the right way to execute two commands in RUN section of the rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the right way to execute 2 commands. I do not like the matching part of your rule either, but I am going to leave it as it is for this example. You could do :

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/mount -t auto /dev/%k /media/ && /usr/local/bin/script.sh'"
```

or

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", RUN+="/bin/mount -t auto /dev/%k /media/", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/script.sh"
```

but in your case why won't you just move the `mount` command inside of your script?